# What is best ORM framework to use with NodeJS and Informix DB. Also Support for Transaction management

Tags: node.js, mybatis, informix

Actually I'm planing to use NodeJS for web application development, my back-end DB is Informix, I'm looking for the ORM framework which best fit for Nodejs and also supports DB Transaction. Previously I used MyBatis with JAVA and Spring I'm wondering whether it supports or not.

Also it is very helpful if someone can provide an example/sample implementation fro CRUD operation using Informix, NodeJS (with or with out ORM)
I searched google with no luck. Appreciate your  help. Thanks In advance

Comment: Let alone an ORM, you will be in luck if you find a well documented npm package with limited bindings.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples in multiple languages (java, javascript, python, etc) to help you get started with app development against Informix backend - https://github.com/ibm-informix/informix-client-examples

Web app development against Informix should be greatly simplified since REST APIs are available for accessing data in relational tables as well as collections. Here is a tutorial on the Informix REST APIs - http://www.slideshare.net/BrianHughes70/informix-rest-api-tutorial

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. It's helpful.